# Redis Laravel - strlen() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given

Tags: php, laravel, caching, redis, lumen

I am trying to cache data in Redis but getting following error:

> ErrorException: strlen() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given
>   /home/mktplacemiddleware/demo/vendor/predis/predis/src/Connection/StreamConnection.php:390

Following is the code i am trying:

```
Redis::set('CacheTest', $finalProduct); //$finalProduct is an Array
```

I am using:

1. redis version 5.5
2. predis version 1.1
3. php version 7.1
4. laravel Lumen 5.7

Any help will be appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to store a data in **serialize or json** try like this:

```
Redis::set('CacheTest', json_encode($finalProduct)); //$finalProduct is an Array
```

and get value you need to **decode** value

```
$data = Redis::get('CacheTest');
dd(json_decode($data))
```